# Fedora XFCE 38 with VBoxGuestAdditions_7.0.8 installed in my Desktop having 32 core machine still bootup taking longer than 2min

Tags: linux, fedora, virtual-machine, xfce, xfce4-terminal

Installed Fedora XFCE 38 `Fedora-Xfce-Live-x86_64-38-1.6.iso` with guest addition `VBoxGuestAdditions_7.0.8`, after installation when I tried to start Linux OS, it is taking more than 2min for boot up, after when I get login screen, after login again it takes more than 1-2min time to login the system.

Anybody faced same issue and have resolution? Which older version of Fedora XFCE is stable and faster? At lest I will go with that for now instead debugging this issue.

I have Desktop with Processor `Ryzen 9 7950X` `16 Core` and `32GB RAM`, and for Fedora box I have given `10 Core`, `10GB RAM`, still boot up time is more than 2min.

**systemd-analyze logs:**

```
[root@vm sf_VMShared]# systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 5.979s (kernel) + 18.274s (initrd) + 1min 40.312s (userspace) = 2min 4.565s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 27.381s in userspace.
[root@vm sf_VMShared]# systemd-analyze blame
21.330s plymouth-quit-wait.service
20.692s sys-module-fuse.device
19.109s sys-module-configfs.device
14.801s polkit.service
14.665s accounts-daemon.service
14.513s udisks2.service
14.429s systemd-user-sessions.service
13.981s dkms.service
13.819s chronyd.service
12.687s dev-disk-by\x2dpartuuid-1056dd3d\x2d3601\x2d4591\x2dbbdc\x2d77ee81504c5d.device
12.687s dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:0d.0\x2data\x2d1.0\x2dpart1.device
12.687s dev-disk-by\x2dpartuuid-b02162a4\x2de23c\x2d4b59\x2da761\x2d385e0cebbb51.device
12.687s dev-disk-by\x2did-ata\x2dVBOX_HARDDISK_VB37693ac4\x2d13fdad05\x2dpart2.device
12.687s dev-sda1.device
12.687s dev-disk-by\x2duuid-43e76b48\x2d6108\x2d475b\x2da7cb\x2d2514a3e73ade.device
12.687s dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-fedora_vm.device
12.687s dev-disk-by\x2ddiskseq-1\x2dpart3.device
12.687s dev-disk-by\x2did-ata\x2dVBOX_HARDDISK_VB37693ac4\x2d13fdad05\x2dpart3.device
12.687s dev-sda3.device
12.687s dev-disk-by\x2ddiskseq-1\x2dpart2.device
12.687s dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:0d.0\x2data\x2d1\x2dpart1.device
12.687s dev-disk-by\x2did-ata\x2dVBOX_HARDDISK_VB37693ac4\x2d13fdad05\x2dpart1.device
12.687s dev-sda2.device
12.687s dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:0d.0\x2data\x2d1\x2dpart2.device
12.687s dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:0d.0\x2data\x2d1.0\x2dpart2.device
12.687s dev-disk-by\x2ddiskseq-1\x2dpart1.device
12.687s sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:0d.0-ata1-host0-target0:0:0-0:0:0:0-block-sda-sda1.device
12.687s dev-disk-by\x2duuid-8239c279\x2d408e\x2d4088\x2da201\x2d53871e84e1ed.device
12.687s sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:0d.0-ata1-host0-target0:0:0-0:0:0:0-block-sda-sda2.device
12.686s dev-disk-by\x2did-ata\x2dVBOX_HARDDISK_VB37693ac4\x2d13fdad05.device
12.686s sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:0d.0-ata1-host0-target0:0:0-0:0:0:0-block-sda.device
12.686s dev-disk-by\x2ddiskseq-1.device
12.686s dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:0d.0\x2data\x2d1.0.device
12.686s dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:0d.0\x2data\x2d1.device
12.686s dev-sda.device
12.679s dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:0d.0\x2data\x2d1\x2dpart3.device
12.679s sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:0d.0-ata1-host0-target0:0:0-0:0:0:0-block-sda-sda3.device
12.679s dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:0d.0\x2data\x2d1.0\x2dpart3.device
12.679s dev-disk-by\x2dpartuuid-15819656\x2d8879\x2d453b\x2dad9e\x2dacd96c724d57.device
12.669s sys-subsystem-net-devices-enp0s3.device
12.669s sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:03.0-net-enp0s3.device
10.789s dev-ttyS0.device
10.789s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS0.device
10.779s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS18.device
10.779s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS2.device
10.779s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS15.device
10.779s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS12.device
10.779s dev-ttyS13.device
10.779s dev-ttyS15.device
10.779s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS19.device
10.779s dev-ttyS18.device
10.779s dev-ttyS11.device
10.779s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS16.device
10.779s dev-ttyS12.device
10.779s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS14.device
10.779s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS11.device
10.779s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS13.device
10.779s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS1.device
10.779s dev-ttyS14.device
10.779s dev-ttyS1.device
10.779s dev-ttyS19.device
10.779s dev-ttyS16.device
10.779s dev-ttyS20.device
10.779s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS17.device
10.779s dev-ttyS17.device
10.779s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS20.device
10.779s dev-ttyS2.device
10.768s dev-ttyS25.device
10.768s dev-ttyS3.device
10.768s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS31.device
10.768s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS28.device
10.768s dev-ttyS7.device
10.768s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS3.device
10.768s dev-ttyS22.device
10.768s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS24.device
10.768s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS30.device
10.768s dev-ttyS24.device
10.768s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS22.device
10.768s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS27.device
10.768s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS9.device
10.768s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS8.device
10.768s dev-ttyS27.device
10.768s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS29.device
10.768s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS7.device
10.768s dev-ttyS31.device
10.768s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS26.device
10.768s dev-ttyS23.device
10.768s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS5.device
10.768s dev-ttyS26.device
10.768s dev-ttyS28.device
10.768s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS21.device
10.768s dev-ttyS29.device
10.768s dev-ttyS30.device
10.768s dev-ttyS9.device
10.768s dev-ttyS4.device
10.768s dev-ttyS5.device
10.768s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS4.device
10.768s dev-ttyS8.device
10.768s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS25.device
10.768s dev-ttyS21.device
10.768s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS23.device
10.768s dev-ttyS6.device
10.768s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS6.device
10.742s dev-ttyS10.device
10.742s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS10.device
 8.491s vboxadd-service.service
 6.801s var-lib-nfs-rpc_pipefs.mount
 6.367s avahi-daemon.service
 6.154s abrtd.service
 5.968s rtkit-daemon.service
 5.808s ModemManager.service
 5.650s systemd-logind.service
 5.553s upower.service
 5.508s vboxservice.service
 4.733s vboxadd.service
 4.353s initrd-switch-root.service
 4.194s firewalld.service
 3.915s NetworkManager.service
 3.394s dracut-shutdown.service
 2.603s systemd-resolved.service
 2.493s systemd-oomd.service
 2.215s user@1000.service
 1.917s systemd-zram-setup@zram0.service
 1.769s systemd-vconsole-setup.service
 1.565s auditd.service
 1.064s user-runtime-dir@1000.service
 1.042s gssproxy.service
 1.006s rpc-statd-notify.service
  992ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
  973ms initrd-cleanup.service
  900ms systemd-sysusers.service
  864ms plymouth-start.service
  791ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-8239c279\x2d408e\x2d4088\x2da201\x2d53871e84e1ed.service
  723ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
  694ms systemd-update-utmp.service
  664ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
  650ms systemd-userdbd.service
  645ms dev-zram0.swap
  623ms home.mount
  601ms modprobe@loop.service
  520ms lightdm.service
  496ms dracut-initqueue.service
  469ms systemd-fsck-root.service
  463ms systemd-remount-fs.service
  448ms rsyslog.service
  442ms plymouth-switch-root.service
  406ms modprobe@fuse.service
  406ms systemd-journal-flush.service
  360ms systemd-network-generator.service
  350ms lvm2-monitor.service
  307ms kmod-static-nodes.service
  289ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
  263ms dracut-cmdline.service
  260ms plymouth-read-write.service
  259ms dev-hugepages.mount
  259ms dev-mqueue.mount
  255ms systemd-modules-load.service
  254ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
  254ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
  240ms dbus-broker.service
  225ms systemd-random-seed.service
  176ms systemd-sysctl.service
  147ms initrd-udevadm-cleanup-db.service
   98ms systemd-udevd.service
   97ms dracut-pre-udev.service
   77ms dracut-pre-pivot.service
   59ms systemd-journald.service
   48ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
   40ms modprobe@dm_mod.service
   40ms modprobe@drm.service
   21ms modprobe@configfs.service
   14ms initrd-parse-etc.service
   13ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
    7ms boot.mount
```